# Django - Nothing happens when "submit" button is clicked in a ModelForm?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Ok, so I am making a project, where you can make new blogposts and edit existing blogposts in Python with Django, but when I want to make a new post on my website, the "submit" button in `new_post.html` does nothing when I press it. I fill in the 'title' field and I fill in the 'text' field from the ModelForm "`BlogPostForm`" and press the button. In the terminal there's no POST or GET request. I just don't know why?
I'm using Python 3.6.4 and Django 2.1, installed in a virtual environment created by the "venv" module.

base.html:

```
<p>
  <a href="{% url 'blogs:index' %}">Blogs</a>
</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "blogs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>All posts:</p>

  <ul>
    {% for blog in blogs %}
      <li>
        {{ blog }}
        <p>{{ blog.date_added|date:'M D, Y H:i' }}</p>
        <p>{{ blog.text|linebreaks }}</p>
        <p>-------------------------------------<p>
      </li>
    {% empty %}
      <li>No posts are posted yet.</li>
      <p>
        <a href="{% url 'blogs:new_post' %}">Add new post</a>
      </p>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  <p>
    <a href="{% url 'blogs:new_post' %}">Add new post</a>
  </p>

{% endblock content %}
```

new_post.html:

```
{% extends "blogs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Make a new post:</p>

  <post action="{% url 'blogs:new_post' %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ post.as_p }}
    <button name='submit'>Add Post</button>
  </post>

{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't your `<post>` tags in `new_post.html` be `<form>` instead?

Comment: If the browser doesn't do anything (does not submit the form) then all the Python stuff is irrelevant. What does the browser's console say? Is a request submitted?

Comment: @RezaKazemirad: good point, that must be it :-)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich There is no request at all in the console, when I press the submit button.

Comment: @LauritsL.L.: so whatever the problem is, it's in the browser (and Reza found the problem). So all the stuff that happens on the server side once the request arrives there -- Python, Django, all that code above couldn't be relevant.

Comment: @RezaKazemirad Wow it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Also thanks to you for explaining. ;-)

Comment: @LauritsL.L. glad it helped you. Please mark my answer below as correct and close this question :)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I've edited my question, so it's only the relevant code, that gets displayed. Thanks!

Comment: @RezaKazemirad Thanks for the helpful answer! I've checked your answer, and thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `<post>` tag in HTML. To post a data you need to use a `<form>` tag. Everything else is correct.